# How to add upload video option in wordpress for user?

Tags: custom-field, media-library, user-meta, uploads

I have a website developed on WordPress.The website is basically job portal. Here in my website two types of user candidate and employer. In my website there is one signup form for both candidate and employer.

Suppose one is registered as candidate then after successful registration. The registered user have to fill their detail like phone, qualification, profile etc.

Here all the filled detail are save in user profile as user meta.

**What i want is?**

I want an upload video option for user type candidate. So that registered candidate can upload their video from front-end. And i want to store the video in separate folder and also want this video in user profile section (user meta).